# Testing the ipa file on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a .ipa file which i want to test in iPad before submitting to iTunes. i can't synchronize it with Xcode because we did not develop the code..we just have a iPad  and .ipa file was sent to us in email, but even i cannot download it through safari shows an error. Is there any possible way to test it.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your iPad a device with authorization to run that .ipa? I mean, is it part of the user's account that signed that .ipa?

Comment: yes Jacky we have authorization

Comment: What I usually do then, I just double click the file, and it will be added to my iTunes. I then sync with the device. Although its strange you are not even able to download it....

Comment: is there any possible way to send .ipa file from system to iPad, as you know the system and iPad device is not together i can't do it through cabel

Comment: You shoud check the above answers. Talk to the developers if you can and check: 1) your device is able to run applications signed by that developer. 2) you are trying to run a debugging application and not a distribution one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a source code it is possible to resign the app using another profile which includes your iPad and even publish to AppStore. You will need Apple Developers account for that.

You can try [www.aironapp.com](http://www.aironapp.com). You need to configure Apple Developers account there and then it could resign the IPA for you and provide OTA download.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to do with an application compiled for distribution. If it would be possible it would mean you could get the ipa's from any device and just run them via iTunes.

You can however ask the developer to send you an ipa compiled for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to installing your App on your iPhone or iPad using .ipa files.

1. We will send you one or two files. One will be a .ipa file and the other will be a .mobileprovision file.  Save them in a convenient location
2. Open iTunes.  Then drag the downloaded .mobileprovision (if provided) & the .ipa files and drop it into iTunes Library.
3. In iTunes select your iPhone (or iPad) under devices.
4. Go to the Apps tab and make sure the checkbox for the new App is checked.  If not, check it yourself.
5. Press Sync.  After it is synced, you should be able to unplug you iPhone and play with the App.

Answer (score 0):

The app probably needs to be signed with a different provisioning profile that includes your iPad.

Comment: what do you mean by "different Provisioning Profile"?

Comment: Apps get signed using "provisioning profiles" which tell the devices where they're allowed to run. Distribution provisioning profiles can't be used to put things on a device. If that's what you have it won't work. Other profiles need to have your device ID embedded in it to be able to run on your device.